# Double OWIN authentication not working together

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

For my website I'm making an integration with a 3rd party authentication provider, using OWIN OpenId, to allow visitors to sign up/sign in/sign out. "Second"

I also have a test environment for my application where all code changes are tested before pushing these changes to production. I shield the test environment from public access with another 3rd party authentication provider, using OWIN OpenId as well "First". Only authenticated visitors can visit the test environment website.

Now the problem is that these both work standalone, but I can't seem to combine them. What I'm trying to achieve is that I can access the test environment by authenticating with First, and then, as a regluar visitor, authenticate with Second to see content designed for registered visitors.

Here's what I'm doing:

Both authnetication providers work with cookie authentication, but I gave them a different AuthenticationType to keep them apart.

```
if (IsEnabled("First"))
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("First");
else
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("Second");

// Configure First.
if (IsEnabled("First")) {
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(First.CookieAuthenticationOptions); // AuthenticationType is set to "First" in these options.
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = First.AADClientId,
        Authority = First.Authority,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = context => { ... },
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = context => { ... }
        },
        AuthenticationType = "First"
    });
    app.Map($"{First.Path}/login", config =>
    {
        config.Run(context =>
        {
            context.Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
                { RedirectUri = First.ReturnUrl, IsPersistent = true  },
                "First"
            );

            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
        });
    });
}

// Configure Second.
app.UseCookieAuthentication(Second.CookieAuthenticationOptions); // AuthenticationType is set to "Second" in these options.
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    UseTokenLifetime = false,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = x => ...,
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = x =>
        {
            var mgr = x.Options.ConfigurationManager as PolicyConfigurationManager;
            if (x.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
            {
                var config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None,
                x.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseRevoke.Properties.Dictionary["PolicyId"]);
                x.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.EndSessionEndpoint;
            }
            else
            {
                var config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None,
                x.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary["PolicyId"]);
                x.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.AuthorizationEndpoint;
            }

            var redirectUri = Second.ReturnPath;
            x.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            x.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri;
        },
        SecurityTokenValidated = x => ...
    },
    Scope = "openid",
    ResponseType = "id_token",
    ReturnUri = Second.ReturnUri,
    ClientId = Second.ClientId,
    ConfigurationManager = GetConfigurationManager()
    AuthenticationType = configuration.AuthenticationType
});
app.Map(Second.LoginPath, config =>
{
    // Trigger unauthorized so that active authentication will redirect to active directory.
    config.Run(context =>
    {
        // Set policy in context to mitigate null ref exception in Startup.Auth OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
        context.Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"PolicyId", Second.LoginPolicyId}
            })
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                RedirectUri = returnUrl
            }, "Second");

        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

        // Middleware will redirect us instead of using this output.
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
    });
});
app.Map(Second.ReturnPath, config =>
{
    config.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        // In case of login, we will never get here because we will get redirected by middleware.
        context.Response.Redirect("/");

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });
});
```

When First is enabled, this allows me to do

```
var identity = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("Second").Result?.Identity;
```

on subsequent requests and have a ClaimsIdentity. But when First is enabled, for some reason the above Result is null.

I've noticed that when I enable both First and Second, and set the DefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType to "Second", it is First that doesn't work anymore. If I enable both First and Second, and browse the site with a previous authentication cookie of First, everything works just fine.

I'm guessing that the return method, that somewhere sets an authentication cookie needs some reference of AuthenticationType, but I don't know where to do that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to add the AuthenticationType to TokenValidationParameters when configuring Second, like so:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    UseTokenLifetime = false,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = x => ...,
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = x =>
        {
            var mgr = x.Options.ConfigurationManager as PolicyConfigurationManager;
            if (x.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
            {
                var config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None,
                x.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseRevoke.Properties.Dictionary["PolicyId"]);
                x.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.EndSessionEndpoint;
            }
            else
            {
                var config = await mgr.GetConfigurationByPolicyAsync(CancellationToken.None,
                x.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary["PolicyId"]);
                x.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = config.AuthorizationEndpoint;
            }

            var redirectUri = Second.ReturnPath;
            x.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            x.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri;
        },
        SecurityTokenValidated = x => ...
    },
    Scope = "openid",
    ResponseType = "id_token",
    ReturnUri = Second.ReturnUri,
    ClientId = Second.ClientId,
    ConfigurationManager = GetConfigurationManager(),
    AuthenticationType = configuration.AuthenticationType,
    // ADD THIS TO MAKE IT WORK:
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            AuthenticationType = configuration.AuthenticationType
        }
});
```